# List and count words from a column

Tags: postgresql, string-searching

I have a column with strings containing a list of species:

```
+----------------------------------------+
|                species                 |
+----------------------------------------+
| Dinosauria, Ornitischia, indeterminado |
| Sirenia                                |
| Dinosauria, Therophoda                 |
| Dinosauria, Therophoda, Allosaurus     |
| and so on...                           |
+----------------------------------------+
```

I am looking for a way, in PostgreSQL 12, to list and count all the unique names such as:

```
+---------------+-------+
|    species    | count |    
+---------------+-------+
| Dinossauria   | 3     |
| Ornitischia   | 1     |
| indeterminado | 1     |                        
| Sirenia       | 1     |    
| Theropoda     | 2     |              
| Allosaurus    | 1     |                 
+-----------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the comma separate list into rows using `regexp_split_to_table()`  and the group by that value:

```
select s.species, count(*)
from the_table t
  cross join regexp_split_to_table(t.species, '\s*,\s*') as s(species)
group by s.species
```

I am using a regex as the delimiter to get rid of the whitespace after the comma.  The above would also be possible with `unnest(string_to_array(t.species, ','))` but then you need to `trim()` the values to get rid of the whitespace.

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=0c03f3860a1de15b172a073087acdcf2)

Comment: Thanks, @a_horse_with_no_name - this is exactly what I had in mind.